# E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/

Tags: package-management, disk-usage

I don't have any storage left in `/dev/sda5` as it shows:

```
/dev/sda5       9.1G  8.8G     0 100% /
```

So, I tried `apt-get clean` and `apt-get autoclean` to no avail. Then, when I tried `apt-get autoremove`, I got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcurl3 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
libnet-ssleay-perl : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
libpython2.7-stdlib : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
libpython3.5-minimal : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
libruby2.3 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is  installed
openssh-client : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
openssh-server : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
openssl : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2g) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
python3-cryptography : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1t-1+deb8u6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

So, I did `apt-get -f install`, but I got errors like this:

```
The following additional packages will be installed:
libssl1.0.0
The following packages will be upgraded:
libssl1.0.0
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,121 kB of archives.
After this operation, 427 kB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.
```

The problem has been so severe that; though I tried to remove any packages or programs to free up some store, it always says:

```
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

**Is there any way out of this ?**
df -h gave me this:

```
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            893M     0  893M   0% /dev
tmpfs           183M  6.1M  177M   4% /run
/dev/sda5       9.1G  8.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs           913M  224K  913M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           913M     0  913M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda6       138G   23G  108G  18% /home
/dev/sda1        96M   56M   41M  58% /boot/efi
tmpfs           183M   52K  183M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       1.9G  861M  1.1G  46% /media/roshan/UBUNTU 16_0
```

ls /boot returned this:

```
enter code heabi-4.4.0-47-generic         memtest86+.elf
abi-4.4.0-75-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
config-4.4.0-47-generic      System.map-4.4.0-47-generic
config-4.4.0-75-generic      System.map-4.4.0-75-generic
efi                          vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-4.4.0-47-generic.efi.signed
initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic
initrd.img-4.4.0-75-generic  vmlinuz-4.4.0-75-generic.efi.signed
memtest86+.binre
```

ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d gave me this:

```
dropbox.list
dropbox.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
jd-team-ubuntu-jdownloader-xenial.list
jd-team-ubuntu-jdownloader-xenial.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list
noobslab-ubuntu-apps-xenial.list.save
opera-stable.list
opera-stable.list.save
slack.list
slack.list.save
tomaszm-ubuntu-dynamics-xenial.list
tomaszm-ubuntu-dynamics-xenial.list.save
xenial-partner.list
xenial-partner.list.save
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list gave me this:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: You will have to free some space by manually deleting files I think. Is your `/home` on a separate partition (show us the output of `df -h`) Is there anything in `/var/cache/apt/archives` besides `partial` and the lock?

Comment: please don't put that in the comments - it's completely unreadable like that - add it to your question please. While you are [edit]ing your question, please show the output of `ls /boot`. Bit worried about your dependency issues though... have you recently upgraded or added some third party repositories?

Comment: Thanks Zanna, I did. But, forgot which package was it ? Also, there are only partial and lock in /var/cache/apt/archives

Comment: wow your root partition is really small. If it's an option for you, consider backing up your data and re-partitioning. You might try running `du -cha --max-depth=1 / 2>/dev/null | grep -Ee "M|G"` to show where the space is being used (add to the question) and possibly you can free a little space by deleting old logs. You can also show `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` to see if we can identify repository issues

Comment: @Zanna I know that I stuffed a bit when made my root partition small. Unfortunately, I don't have any external data device for now, and I also have to back up loads of data for this to do. Can we do something just for some couple of days ? Is there any solution till me, I will be very grateful. Thanks,. Besides, I don't want to back it up into my Windows partition. This time I want to install only linux.

Comment: did you try running the `du` command I mentioned? What was the output?

Comment: 861M /media
6.8G /usr
6.1M /run
23G /home
580M /var
66M /etc
640M /root
13M /bin
13M /sbin
621M /lib
175M /boot
33G /
33G total

Comment: it's all in `/usr` (installed software) - hardly anything in `/var`, so really difficult to recommend anything. You can run `sudo find /var/log -type f -name "*.gz"` and then run the same command again with `-delete` on the end to remove old logs but this will only clear a few K. Unlikely to be enough even to let apt download packages, but it might be enough to let apt remove packages - if there is anything you don't need like Opera, Chrome etc, try to remove it.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried to remove opera, but it is not letting me to remove it. I don't know why ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62677/discussion-between-zanna-and-roshan-shrestha).

Comment: Since you have space in your home directory, you can try Rinzwind's solution to the linked post, but instead of making a symlink to `/media`, use `sudo mv -i /var/cache/apt $HOME && sudo ln -s $HOME/apt /var/cache/apt` as a temporary solution until you can repartition or reinstall